# How to negate a disjunction

Tags: ruby, boolean-logic, demorgans-law

I am a little confused with [Enumerator#reject](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M001489) in ruby. Consider the following code:

```
(1..10).select {|i| i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0 } => [3, 5, 6, 9, 10]
```

Shouldn't the following line be equivalent?

```
(1..10).reject {|i| i % 3 != 0 || i % 5 != 0 } => []
```

If I just use one condition on the reject method, the result is as expected. but If I include the OR operator the result turns out to be empty. Could somebody clarify this for me.

```
(1..10).reject {|i| i % 3 != 0} => [3, 6, 9]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are making a basic logic mistake:

`!(A || B)` is equivalent to `!A && !B` and NOT equivalent to `!A || !B`.

So if you change the `||` in your second example to a `&&`, then your second example would give the same result as the first:

```
(1..10).reject {|i| i % 3 != 0 && i % 5 != 0 } # => [3, 5, 6, 9, 10]
```

Answer (score 3):

You have run into one of [De Morgan's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).

*p* And *q* = Not((Not *p*) Or   (Not *q*))
*p* Or   *q* = Not((Not *p*) And (Not *q*))

It was close, but you forgot to change the operator.

Answer (score 0):

In the second piece of code, you changed the equality, so you'll need to change the `||` to `&&`.

```
(1..10).reject {|i| i % 3 != 0 && i % 5 != 0 } => [3, 5, 6, 9, 10]
```